# A quotient ring isomorphic to a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

Let $a_1,\ldots,a_m \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]:=S$, with $m > n \geq 2$.

Denote $R:=\mathbb{C}[a_1,\ldots,a_m]$ and assume that $I$ is an ideal of $R$
such that $R/I \cong \mathbb{C}[x_{r+1},\ldots,x_n]$, for some $1 \leq r \leq n-1$.

If I am not wrong, there exists an automorphism $f$ of $S$ such that
$f(I) \subseteq Sx_1+\cdots+Sx_r$ (= the ideal in $S$ generated by $x_1,\ldots,x_r$).

> **Question:** Is it true that there exists an automorphism $g$ of $S$ such that the images of the generators $a_1,\ldots,a_m$ under $g$, $g(a_1),\ldots,g(a_m)$, belong to $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_r]$?

**Example:** $a_1=x^2, a_2=x^3, a_3=y$, $R=\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3,y]$, $S=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.
Take $I=Rx^2+Rx^3$.
$R/I$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[y]$. ($n=2$, $m=3$, $r=1$).
Here $I \subseteq Sx$ and the generators of $I$, $x^2$ and $x^3$, belong to $\mathbb{C}[x]$. Here $f=g$ the identity map: $f(s)=s$ for every $s \in S$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: In your Example $R/I$ is also isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[x]$, but $I$ is not contained in $Sy$.

Comment: @Francesco, thank you, good point! I now edited the question. Hopefully, it is better now.

Comment: I think it fails with $I=xyk[xy]\subset k[x,y]$.

Comment: Yes sorry for the ambiguity. Say $R=k[xy,z],I=(xy),S=k[x,y,z]$. My idea is that $k[xy]$ is integrally closed in $k[x,y,z]$ so if $g(xy)\in k[x]$ then $g(xy)=ax+b$ so that $k[x,y,z]=k[xy,g^{-1}(y),g^{-1}(z)]$ which is absurd by looking at the $k$-dimension of the image in $k[x,y,z]/(x,y,z)^2$.

Comment: @reuns, thank you for your comment. Please, did you mean that $R=k[xy]$, $I=Rxy$, $S=k[x,y]$? Then $R/I \cong \mathbb{C}$, and in my question $r \geq 1$. Also, $R=k[xy,z]$, $I=xyR$, $S=k[x,y,z]$; now $R/I \cong \mathbb{C}[z]$. $I \subseteq Sx+Sy$, but $I \not \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ ($xyz \in I$ but $xyz \not \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$), so this is a counterexample.

Comment: @reuns, thank you for the explanation. Please, at least, is the following true: "If I am not wrong, there exists an automorphism $f$ of $S$ such that
$f(I) \subseteq Sx_1+\cdots+Sx_r$ (= the ideal in $S$ generated by $x_1,\ldots,x_r$)."?